# Visitor pattern with multiple argument

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

Is it possible to implement the visitor pattern such that:

1. Multiple visitors can be used on the acceptor.
2. The acceptor must not change when new visitors are added.
3. Visitors might have to receive arguments and the number and types of arguments are different between visitors.

An example is a Shape hierarchy class and operations that can be performed on the shapes. If the operations does not have to receive any arguments, than each operation can be a visitor and inherit from Visitor class, and each shape will implement the accept method:

```
void SomeShape::accept(Visitor* visitor)
{
    visitor->visit(*this);
}
```

However, is there a way to use the visitor pattern in case each visitor need to receive additional arguments? Are there any good alternatives?

Comment: This might be better suited to programmers.stackexchange.com, it's more of a design question

Comment: @MarcoA. I disagree : the design is already chosen, this is a technical question about how to apply it. OP : what would be an example of additional arguments ?

Comment: Doesn't the pattern assume that all parameters are encapsulated in the visitor?

Comment: Arguments can be anything from a simple double to a custom class (Such as Point).

Comment: Fine, but where should their values typically come from ?

Comment: From the caller. Class A want to perform operation P on shape with a specific Point as an argument

Comment: Then I think o_weisman has a point. Do you have a specific case where you can't have the Visitor self-contained ?

Comment: I can store the parameters in the Visitor before calling accept. I am not sure if it will result in good code, but it will work

Comment: @ErikSapir it may seem strange at first, but it's an idiomatic and powerful way of doing it. It's a pattern similar to functors.

Comment: Let me see if i understand it correctly: Say i have a Snapper class that is a Visitor. Snapper implements snapToPoint(Shape* shape, Point* point). When calling snapToPoint snapper stores the point in a member variable and calls shape->aceept() that will result in a call back to the snapper to the visit function. Am i correct about the way of implementation?

Comment: @ErikSapir see my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to store your additional parameters in the Visitor itself. They are usually passed in the constructor. That's called *reification* ("making real") : what would have been a function call with parameters is now an object, representing the function call, and storing the parameters. You can now pass this object around without looking inside, which is what we want.

Your `accept` function should take a `Visitor const&` so that you can pass it temporaries, which is handy :

```
pShape->accept(SnapToPoint(x, y));
```

The `SnapToPoint` class will look like that :

```
struct SnapToPoint : Visitor {
    SnapToPoint(float x, float y) : _point(x, y) {}

    void visit(Circle   &c) const override { /* Use _point on c */ }
    void visit(Triangle &t) const override { /* Use _point on t */ }
    void visit(Square   &s) const override { /* Use _point on s */ }

private:
    Point _point;
};
```

**Edit:** In response to the dependency injection need below, an example of a Visitor Factory :

```
struct ShapeOperationFactory {
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Visitor> snapToPoint(float x, float y) const = 0;
};

struct MyShapeOpFactory : ShapeOperationFactory {
    std::unique_ptr<Visitor> snapToPoint(float x, float y) const override {
        return std::unique_ptr<Visitor>(new SnapToPoint(x, y));
    }
};
```

Which would be called like that :

```
ShapeOperationFactory *pFactory = /* Get a factory */;
pShape->accept(pFactory->snapToPoint(4.0f, 7.0f));
```

See it working [here](http://ideone.com/sI1SGD). Note that I had to take `Visitor` instances by `std::unique_ptr` this time, since the factory is generic.

**Edit 2:** Refreshed my memory about temporaries lifetime. I've rolled back the `accept` function to taking a `Visitor const&`, see results [here](http://ideone.com/OwgEAU).

Comment: What if i prefer to have one such SnapToPoint visitor and not create a new one for each point? Is my suggestion in the comment to the original question seems OK?

Comment: @ErikSapir It would work, but you'll have a mutable reified call. While technically working, things can get hairy if you use it multiple times, so you'll have to make sure the "calls" don't overlap. Note that creating temporaries has no performace hit, thanks to optimizing compilers.

Comment: It has no performance hit but it means i could not do dependency injection.

Comment: @ErikSapir then a Factory object producing instances of SnapToPoint would be injectable. Albeit a bit overkill maybe.

Comment: Does sound like an overkill. Although it might be the best option to introduce DI with this Visitor implementation

Comment: @ErikSapir there you go, an example factory.

Comment: Why do you need MyShapeOpFactory? Why not ShapeOperationFactory has the actual implementation?

Comment: @ErikSapir well, `ShapeOperationFactory` is the interface of your factory Dependency. It's up to you now to Inject a concrete instance (here of `MyShapeOpFactory`). Or did I miss your point about DI ?

Answer (score 0):

You are on thin barieer of decision.

There is no way to do what you ask *in visitor pattern*, if yes it will not more visitor pattern, as main responsibility of it is define set of functions to execute over pile of data keeping abstraction high enough to avoid concrete type identification in `Acceptor`.

You *may* still have that what you're asking for: for example you may keep some state variables/(unions) inside visitor itself, so executing `accept` on it will produce different result based on internal state of concrete `Visitor` instance.

Comment: So it means that i set my arguments to the Visitor before perform accept on the Shape. Do you think it is a good practice to do this?

Comment: @ErikSapir: either it good or not it depends on your program structure. In general, holding the state of object that *should*, according to the logic application and your question, affect reposnce of that concrete instance on accept call, seems legit. On the cons side, you may look on: how often you need this vistorn pattern, do you really need preserve states in every instance, *if*, repeat *if* this visitor accept call is something rare in your system. totally good choice one can make only knowing how your system works in overall.